# Strophe.js Ping error when without SID

Tags: ping, strophe, strophe.js

I am having an error, when i use ping without the user SID. DO i have to know the receiver's SID for the ping to work?? Or can i just ping a user to see if he is online or not without an SID with just the Userid like jid1@server.com?

Edit: I am using Ping plugin from Strophe.js

```
RECV: <body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'><iq xmlns='jabber:client' from='jid1@server.com' to='jid2@server.com/5250814551463483065313851' type='error' id='2:From Page2'><ping xmlns='urn:xmpp:ping'/><error code='503' type='cancel'><service-unavailable xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/></error></iq></body>
```

Comment: Have you tried with Strophe ping plugin (https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugins/tree/master/ping)?

Comment: I did, that is what i am using. Sorry for not mentioning it in the content above. But ping is returning error, and receiver isnt getting anything if i dont put in an SID even using Strophe.js